# Why script with Tensorflow.js src doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

If I remove `src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js"` then it shows my alert. What's wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Brain Tumor </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js">
alert("alert"); // doesn't work if there's src

/*async function LoadModels(){  
           model = undefined;
           model = await tf.loadLayersModel("D:/user/diploma/models/models/model.json");
           const image = tf.fromPixels("D:/user/diploma/IM-0115-0001.jpeg");
           const prediction = model.predict(image);
           alert(prediction);
       }
       LoadModels();*/

</script>

</head>
...
</html>
```

**EDIT:**[image]

Comment: That's not related with `Tensorflow.js`. Its the issue with `platform_browser.js` file path, which is not correct.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But why it's not correct? I just copied filepath to model.json. I tried both Github path to this file and path to local file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `alert` in another `script` tag.

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<script>
alert("alert");
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it too, but it gives me another 2 errors, like Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your console with complete error?

Comment: Sure! Edited...